# CData components - SSIS

Tags: ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

my company recently started migrating some of our DBs to Snowflake. I have been tasked with finding a resource to modify our SSIS packages to point to snowflake.

I have found this company CDATA and already tried their SSIS components and the product works fine when I run any SSIS package locally on my machine but it fails when I schedule the package in SSMS. The job failure description reads "CDATA connection manager is not a valid connection source"

I followed up with the company who did not have an answer and only suggested to install the same components on the server after I asked if that was the cause of the failure

Also is there any other way to connect to snowflake in SSIS?

Thanks,

Comment: Main integration options are listed here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Integrating-SSIS-with-Snowflake

Comment: Given that you are moving to Snowflake and, as you've discovered, Snowflake and SSIS don't play well together - are you planning to move to a different ETL tool? Do you need a temporary solution while you move to a new tool or does this need to be a permanent fix? Roughly how many SSIS jobs are there that need to be fixed?

Comment: Whatever you installed on your local machine to get the CDATA SSIS components would also have to be installed on the server where the SSIS package is deployed and running from.

Comment: Hi Nick, yes it would be a permanent fix.. we would have roughly 50-60 jobs running daily that would need to be modified to point to snowflake.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Yes just today i was able to install the components on the server.. The test job i have failed when i run it in SSMS via SA job but when I logged into the server and executed the package it worked

Comment: The error is something to do with installation. I would suggest you to use  CDATA's uninstall tool to fully uninstall and then re-install the component. Also, check how the job is scheduled and the connection string it uses while running in the server.